# In Kohana, can you trigger a 404 error?

Tags: php, kohana, http-status-code-404

I have a controller called `articles`, which creates the articles model which gets the relevant data from the database.

I want to, if the method I call returns `false`, to trigger a 404 error. This is what I have so far.

```
 $articleName =  $this->uri->segment('articles');

 $article = new Articles_Model();

 $data = $article->getArticleUsingSlug($articleName);

 if (!$data) {
    Kohana::show_404; // This doesn't work.
 }
```

I just added my own custom hook which redirects the user to an actual 404 (/articles/page-not-found/) as triggered by Kohana, but is there a way I can invoke its internal 404 method to make Kohana give up processing my controller and use my new hook ?

Comment: Can't you just use the php header method and then die()?

Comment: @Nael El Shawwa Not when there are better options available.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Event::run('system.404');
```

What version of Kohana are you using?

Comment: Also note that if $config['display_errors'] = TRUE; you will see a stack trace along with your 404 page. If you want JUST a 404 page to display set display_errors = FALSE

Answer (score 11):

Kohana / General / Error-handling / [Kohana_404_Exception](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/errorhandling#kohana_404_exception)

```
/**
 * @param  string  URL of page
 * @param  string  custom error template
 */
throw new Kohana_404_Exception([string $page [, string $template]]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - better late than never! +1

Comment: Somebody else may stumble across this question in the future :)

Comment: As an update, in Kohana 3.3 it’s `throw new Kohana_HTTP_Exception_404()`.

Answer (score 1):

[Kohana Docs](https://v2docs.kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/errors#http-exception-handling) tells you way to do it:

```
throw HTTP_Exception::factory(404, 'File not found!');
```